# How serialize one listener and don't serialize other listener of same event

Tags: c#, serialization

I have two objects(both serializable) in domain model and one winform control. First object and  winform control are listeners of the same event of second object. I want serialize second object with first object as listener and without winform control listener.

```
class SecondObject
{ 
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent; 
}

class FirstObject
{
    SecondObject object;
    object.SomeEvent += secondObject_SomeEvent();
}

class WinFormControl
{
    SecondObject object;
    object.SomeEvent += secondObject_SomeEvent(); 
}
```

Right now, i do it so:

```
class SecondObject
{ 
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent; 
}

class FirstObject
{
    SecondObject object;

    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void SubscribeToEventsOnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
         object.SomeEvent += secondObject_SomeEvent();
    }       
}
```

But can i do it without NonSerialized event?

P.s. sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I would strongly advise: **do not serialize events... ever**. That is pure implementation, where-as serialization should be  talking *data*.

With `BinaryFormatter` (which is, I assume, what you are using) the only way to selectively serialize this would be to implement `ISerializable` and do all the work yourself, but frankly I strongly advise against it - just as strongly as I advise against serializing events in the first place (of course, I also routinely caution people about using `BinaryFormatter` in the first place, especially if the intent is to store the data somewhere - too many horror stories...)

Comment: Which way of serializing data do you prefer? XmlSerializer or even something different?

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih depends on the requirements; json and xml are versatile and flexible options for many common scenarios; a lot of stuff I work on tends to be performance-critical (CPU, bandwidth, or more often: both) - so I tend to use protobuf-net a lot... plus: I'm kinda biased

Comment: Thanks for answering that fast, I am currently using Xml, but will surely take a look at protobuf-net and json

Comment: OK. Thx for advises. I will not serialize events. And will read about serializations you mentioned.